# Preg_replace_callback colocar texto antes do número

Tags: php

Eu tenho um texto que segue assim: Id - Nome: Idade - Telefone

500 - Antonio: Idade: 35 anos - telefone 3681-08xx
Preferências: andar de bicicleta, viajar.
1.500 - Rodrigo: Idade: 20 anos - telefone 3685-40xx
Preferências: Jogar dançar, ler livro.

Gostaria de colocar nas frases que começam com números a informação "Id: ", para ficar assim:

ID: 500 - Antonio: Idade: 35 anos - telefone 3681-08xx
Preferências: andar de bicicleta, viajar.
ID: 1.500 - Rodrigo: Idade: 20 anos - telefone 3685-40xx
Preferências: Jogar dançar, ler livro.

Como faço isso com preg_replace_callback?

Comment: E como essa frase é montada?

Comment: é um texto corrido, sem marcação, gostaria de pesquisar o texto todo, e aonde conter uma frase que comece com número inserir o texto "ID : "

Comment: Isso não serviria?  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba45ef3ae5b0d84238fcc58665d20385c1c9f5e2

Comment: Serviu como uma luva, muito obrigado man

Comment: Vou por como resposta e add uma explicação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solução alternativa

> A conversão de string para inteiro depende do formato da string, assim o PHP avalia o formato da string e caso não possua nenhum valor numérico será convertido para 0(zero). **Caso possua valor numérico em sua primeira posição** o valor será considerado e caso o valor não seja na primeira posição será desconsiderado. Portanto podemos aproveitar essa conversão na condicional:

```
$string  = '500 - Antonio: Idade: 35 anos - telefone 3681-08xx
Preferências: andar de bicicleta, viajar.';

if ((int)($string)) { 
   $string  = "Id: " .$string;
}

echo $string ;
```

Veja funcionando no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/m1FJiL)

Comment: Mirou no tatu, acertou o caititu! :D

Answer (score 1):

Outra possível solução utilizando regex:

```
$linha = '500 - Antonio: Idade: 35 anos';
$novaLinha = preg_match('#^\d#', $linha) ?
             sprintf('Id: %s', $linha) :
             $linha;

echo $novaLinha . PHP_EOL;
// Id: 500 - Antonio: Idade: 35 anos
```

Regex:

```
^\d - string iniciada com dígitos
```

[exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/sHmctL)